# Hide a table row in Telerik's RadRichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I'm currently doing some work with Telerik's controls (`RadRichTextBox` specifically).

We've got a requirement to be able to toggle row visibility on tables in the document.

Setting `TableRow`.`Height` to 0 has **no effect** on the actual visual state of the row if there are contents in any of the cells.

I gather this is likely down to the content having their own height and as such the layout pass is deciding to keep the row at the same height.

I can't find any sort of visibility property (naturally), so I'm at a bit of a loss as to how I go about solving this one.

An approach my team has come up with (which none of us like) is to basically keep track of "last known" formatting information via a serialised tag object against the row / cell, when collapsing a row do so for everything and persist the old data and just re hydrate to reverse - this isn't ideal as it means walking every `cell` for a `paragraph` and then walk those for `spans`.

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't have a `Visibility` property because it is not a `FrameworkElement`. Most of the controls that you are manipulating inside `FlowDocument` children are called `FrameworkContentElement`.

Setting `TableRow.Height` to 0 is not a good idea and it'll just mess up the look and feel of the `UI` when you use serialization and deserialization against the document.

In my opinion what I would do is create `attach properties` for `TableRows` and when user `toggles` to hide the `TableRows` you clear all the `TableCells` of the `TableRow` and when they put it back you'll just have to re-add it back. Better than walking to every cell and paragraph.

Comment: If you read the question you'll see it's the Telerik control suite and their document system, not stock WPF.

Comment: @Clint Go downvote, underneath the `Telerik control suite` specifically `RadRichTextBox` is using `FrameworkContentElement`. I know what I am talking about. Disclaimer: I've been doing weird and fun stuff with `FlowDocuments` and `Telerik's Document system`

Comment: Your idea about the attached properties is interesting, any idea about how you'd tackle this? I'd like to remove the downvote but it won't let me unless the answer is edited. A code sample / pseudocode would be greatly appreciated :)